# Spark Job Split puzzled

Tags: apache-spark

When I start learning spark, I find a question about job split. If I use code like this:

```
sql = "select username, age, address, email from user"
data = sqlContext.sql(sql)
data.show()
```

Normally, operation show shoule generate one job, but I find two jobs in fact. I am puzzled.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

So why the operation "show" generator two jobs?